# Mutual information: Indirect

Tags: information-theory

Maybe this is a very trivial question but my own answer to it is rather based on intuition only.
Consider two random variables **A** and **B**. Their mutual information is **I_AB**. Now, I want to obtain information about **B**, but it is not possible. I can only access **A** such that my own variable **C** shares some information with **A**, **I_AC**. In this case, what would be the mutual Information between my variable **C** and the inaccessible variable **B**, that would be **I_BC**? My intuition would say that it must be **I_BC = I_AC*I_AB / I_AA** where **I_AA** is the full information of **A**. Is this intuition correct? Is there a proof of this, somewhere?

best regards

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can really say about the mutual information $I(B;C)$ other than that it is smaller than $I(A;B)$ (this is the so-called data processing inequality). The problem to maximize $I(B;C)$ for a given $I(A;C)$ is dealt with in the information bottleneck problem.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. But isn't there at least a special case where _**I{B;C} = I{A;C}*I{A;B} / I{A;A}**_ would be true? For example for gaussian, not self-correlated variables A,B and C?

Comment: Sure, there can always be such a case: A trivial one would be $A=B=C$, for an arbitrary distribution of $A$. Then, $I(A;B)=I(A;C)=I(B;C)=I(A;A)=H(A)$, and hence the terms in your denominator cancel.